# Python AWS Lambda Certificates

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate

How do I add an additional CA (certificate authority) to the trust store used by my Python3 AWS Lambda function?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  What is "one of the external services" and why would a certificate be needed?

Comment: I am accessing a rest service over https. I believe I need a certificate to be installed in truststore in case of a java application , but since a python app running on AWS Lambda I’m unsure as to how it can be implemented

Comment: This question is pretty unclear. Are you asking about any particular certificate? if it is a valid certificate that has a chain from a trusted CA you probably don't need to do anything. However if you are using self signed certificate, that would be different.

Comment: [this may be useful](https://askdba.org/weblog/2020/09/using-ssl-to-securely-connect-to-amazon-redshift-cluster/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need a single CA, then get your crt file and encode it into a pem using the following command in linux:

> openssl x509 -text -in "{your CA}.crt" > cacert.pem

If you need to add CA's to the default CA bundle, then copy python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem to your lambda folder. Then run this command for each crt:

> openssl x509 -text -in "{your CA}.crt" >> cacert.pem

After creating the pem file, deploy your lambda with the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable set to **/var/task/cacert.pem**.

/var/task is where AWS Lambda extracts your zipped up code to.

Comment: this made my calls to aws not work du to ssl validation, seems it added my cert but removed defaults ones?

Comment: @FranklinRivero Did you copy the original cacert.pem bundle and append yours to it? I honestly only needed to access one service so I didn't test that part myself.

Comment: I ended up using  CURL_CA_BUNDLE instead and worked iwth both aws services and mine, how can I get the original cacert.pem used for accessing aws services (ssm,dynamodb,batch, sns and few others I call). if I print REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE it doesn't give me anything.

Comment: @FranklinRivero It should be what's in python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem by default. But I guess it's possible that Amazon adds their certs to the standard python certs.